# How to print out the type of a list in Scala?

Tags: scala, reflection, type-erasure

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

`val ex = List[String]("a", "b", "c")
typePrinter(ex)  //prints out "List[String]"`

Is this possible in Scala? The standard `.getClass` doesnt seem to work here. Thanks!

Comment: It is strange that .getClass is not working. Can you show ho you have tried because it will work?

Comment: it is working fine

scala> ex.getClass
res13: Class[_ <: List[String]] = class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon

Comment: Maybe that's true in the repl? I'm trying this on https://scastie.scala-lang.org/

When I do `println(List(1).getClass)`, I get 

`class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon`

Answer (score 8):

Chaitanya's approach is the correct one. That said, my understanding is that in Scala 2.12 `ClassTag` and `TypeTag` are preferred over `Manifest`. Here's a way to do this with `TypeTag`:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._


def getClassName[T : TypeTag](input: T) : String = {
  typeOf[T].toString
}
val ex = List[String]("a", "b", "c")
println(getClassName(ex)) // prints "List[String]"
```

The reason for this is that type erasure means that at runtime, the fact that your `List` was declared with generic parameter `String` is simply not there anymore. Adding a context bound for `ClassTag` or `TypeTag` means that you introduce an implicit parameter for `ClassTag[T]` or `TypeTag[T]`, which the compiler will generate for you when it encounters the dependency. These parameters encode the type information that would be lost otherwise, and can be used in methods like `typeOf` to pull out more type information than is available on the class instance itself.

Comment: Not just in Scala 2.12, but since 2.10, 5 years now :)

Answer (score 4):

You can declare a function typeWriter like this

```
def typePrinter[T: Manifest](t: T): Manifest[T] = manifest[T]
```

Then for the input

```
val ex = List[String]("a", "b", "c")
```

when you invoke the typeWriter function with the given value as the input you will get the type information

```
typePrinter(ex)
```

output as

```
res0: Manifest[List[String]] = scala.collection.immutable.List[java.lang.String]
```

Also if you are in scala repl mode you can get the type level information by using ' :type '

```
scala> val ex = List[String]("a", "b", "c")
ex: List[String] = List(a, b, c)

scala> :type ex
List[String]
```